# Delphi: How to access clientdataset via delta

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

On the TDatasetProvider.OnBeforeUpdateRecord, how do I
access the source or originating clientdataset of the 
sent DeltaDS parameter?

```
procedure TdmLoanPayment.dpLoanPaymentBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
    SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind:  TUpdateKind;
    var Applied: Boolean);
var
  sourceCDS: TClientDataset;
begin
  sourceCDS := DeltaDS.???;
  ...
end;
```

I need to access some properties from the corresponding clientdataset. Setup is TSQLDataset/TDatasetProvider/TClientDataset.

**Edit:**
The cause of all this hassle is, I wanted to derive a component from TDatasetProvider and assign a default OnBeforeUpdateRecord.

Comment: You seem to be somewhat confused. `SourceDS` is the source (originating) dataset, and `DeltaDS` contains the changes that have occurred in `SourceDS`.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but I'm not confused. I know what SourceDS is. What I want to know is which Clientdataset generated the DeltaDS in question.

Comment: Of course, while designing, this is not really a problem because I can tell which CDS is connected. But I am trying to abstract this process.

Comment: What is mean "default OnBeforeUpdateRecord"?  Is not OnBeforeUpdateRecord event of the provider?

Comment: @ValMarinov, I wanted to derive/descend a component from TDatasetProvider. On this descendant component I will assign an OnBeforeUpdateRecord that will always be evaluated. Inside this OnBeforeUpdateRecord I wanted to know the Clientdataset that generated/parented the delta that was passed to this event.

Comment: And I've told you that, but you're not listening. **SourceDS** is the *Clientdataset which generated the DeltaDS*. Read my first comment again.

Comment: Ok, Ken. I see the merit of what you are saying. SourceDS IS the source dataset, but I'm sure it's NOT the clientdataset I'm looking for. Kindly track back to the comments for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think `SourceDS` is what are looking for.

> The **Sender** parameter identifies the provider that is applying updates.
>
> The **SourceDS** parameter is the dataset from which the data originated.
>   If there is no source dataset, this value is nil (Delphi) or NULL
>   (C++). The source dataset may not be active when the event occurs, so
>   set its Active property to true before trying to access its data.
>
> The **DeltaDS** parameter is a client dataset containing all the updates
>   that are being applied. The current record represents the update that
>   is about to be applied.
>
> The **UpdateKind** parameter indicates whether this update is the
>   modification of an existing record (ukModify), a new record to insert
>   (ukInsert), or an existing record to delete (ukDelete).
>
> The **Applied** parameter controls what happens after exiting the event
>   handler. If the event handler sets Applied to true, the provider
>   ignores the update: it neither tries to apply it, nor does it log an
>   error indicating that the update was not applied. If the event handler
>   leaves Applied as false, the provider tries to apply the update after
>   the event handler exits.

for example:

```
procedure TdmLoanPayment.dpLoanPaymentBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind:  TUpdateKind;
var Applied: Boolean);
begin
  ShowMessage(TClientDataSet(SourceDS).Name); // get source name
  ...
end;
```

**Edit**

or

```
  procedure TdmLoanPayment.dpLoanPaymentBeforeUpdateRecord(Sender: TObject;
SourceDS: TDataSet; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet; UpdateKind:  TUpdateKind;
var Applied: Boolean);
begin
  if SourceDS.Name = 'Name1'then
    ...do something ...
  if SourceDS.Name = 'Name2'then
    ...do something ... 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Val. But are you sure you can covert/cast SourceDS as TClientdataset? Because in my setup, SourceDS would be a TSQLDataset. In my setup (SQLDS => Provider => CDS), what I'm looking for is a way to reference CDS (that's the source). This is no problem while designing, but I am trying to do this at runtime in order to encapsulate.

Comment: No I'm not sure. But  in your question and in your setup(SQLDS => Provider => CDS) it is TClientDataSet.

Comment: But you may use it as is (`TDataSet`) if you don't sure.

Comment: No, Val, that's not what I want. May I also refer you to my edit in the question and the comments below it for possible clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace out of the call to your `DataSetProvider1BeforeUpdateRecord`, you'll
see that the dataset passed as the SourceDS parameter is the `Source` dataset of
the `UpdateTree`, and that is, AFAICS, the dataset that the `DataSet` property of
the Provider is set to.  Of course, this is **not** the CDS from which the Delta
has been derived (in my test case it's actually a TAdoQuery).

Looking at the source code in Provider.Pas, I can't immediately see a
way to find the identity of the Delta's source CDS.  I don't think that is particularly surprising because the Provider's operation is invoked by a CDS and not vice versa, and all the data the Provider needs from the CDS is its Delta.

On the other hand, it's a pretty fair bet that the BeforeUpdateRecord event has
been triggered by the most recent, still-pending, call to ApplyUpdates on one of your CDSs, so if
you make a note of that in their `BeforeApplyUpdates` event(s), that will probably
tell you what you want to know.  I'd expect that to work for a single-level update, but it might be more tricky if the `UpdateTree` is operating on nested CDSs.

If your CDSs all have individual Providers, but the providers share a BeforeUpdateRecord event, you could identify the CDS for a given provider using code like this:

```
function TCDSForm.FindCDSForProvider(DataSetProvider: TDataSetProvider):
    TClientDataSet;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    if Components[i] is TClientDataSet then
      if TClientDataSet(Components[i]).ProviderName = DataSetProvider.Name then begin
        Result := TClientDataSet(Components[i]);
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This probably is the only way to get to the clientdataset then, albeit being brutish. I will try this tonight.